# Handling display orientation on startup

Tags: blackberry-10, screen-orientation, blackberry-cascades

I'll start with an example

```
ImageButton {
    defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/test_p.png"
    pressedImageSource: "asset:///images/test_p_pressed.png"

    attachedObjects: [ 
        OrientationHandler { //gives "orientation"
            onOrientationAboutToChange: {
                if (orientation == UIOrientation.Landscape) {
                    defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/test_l.png"
                    pressedImageSource = "asset:///images/test_l_pressed.png"
                } else {
                    defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/test_p.png"
                    pressedImageSource = "asset:///images/test_p_pressed.png"
                } 
            }
        }
    ]  
}
```

Screen rotation works just fine, when it's landscape it uses _l, when it's portrait it uses _p image. The problem is, when I start app in landscape, it will show _p, not _l image (because it's default). How do I check orientation in onCreationCompleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's an obvious one really. You put id to your OrientationHandler, and then you use it in onCreationCompleted.

```
ImageButton {
    defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/test_p.png" //do I still need this?
    pressedImageSource: "asset:///images/test_p_pressed.png"

    attachedObjects: [ 
        OrientationHandler { //gives "orientation"
        id: orientationHandler //make id so you can call it
            onOrientationAboutToChange: {
                changeImages(orientation);
            }
        }
    ]  
    function changeImages(orientation){
        if (orientation == UIOrientation.Landscape) {
            defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/test_l.png"
            pressedImageSource = "asset:///images/test_l_pressed.png"
        } else {
            defaultImageSource = "asset:///images/test_p.png"
            pressedImageSource = "asset:///images/test_p_pressed.png"
        } 
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        changeImages(orientationHandler.orientation); //call it here
    }
}
```